# CoreData Model Super Entity without Attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, core-data, singleton

I am creating a Core Data project. I have watched many tutorials and read documents. I can create an `NSManagedObject`, `NSManagedObjectContext` and `NSFetchRequest` no problem. I want to ensure I create my project in the correct way though so:

My app will list favourite football and basketball players;

I created 3 entity;

1. -`PlayersList` Entity - No attributes here. Because I want to use football and basketball entity properties
2. -`Football` Entity - attributes = `PlayerName`
3. -`Basketball` Entity - attributes = `basketPlayerName`

[image]

And I added relationship `PlayerList` to Many to `Football`s and ofc `football` to `PlayerList` single relationship.  `PlayerList` to Many to `Basketball`s and `basketball` to `PlayerList` single relationship. And set them as inverses.

I have an `NSSet` in my `PlayersList`. Should I use this ?

And I have a `PlayersListTableViewController`. I can fetch `Football` entity and list my tableview or `Basketball` entity. But I cant fetch `PlayersList` Entity because it hasn't any attributes. Main question is:

How can I list all playernames in my `PlayersListTableViewController` ?

How can I use 2 entity attributes from 1 super entity ? like `footPlayerName` and `basketPlayerName`.

Comment: A picture paints a thousand words... Link to a picture of your data model.

Comment: http://s13.postimg.org/c8f48sj6f/image.jpg There is the my data model.If I do this single Player Entity how can i know which one is basketball or which one is football ? And how can i list these datas from another controller to only football players ? And its a easy concept I will add another attributes like footballerAge or footballerFoot. If i do that single Player Entity it contains too many attributes. I just want to show all attributes from 1 tableviewcontroleler.

Comment: If I don't create a PlayerList entity how can I list another entity properties from my tableview. I can fetch and list Football entity attributes with my fetchResultsController in this way I cant fetch Basketball entity attributes.Because I fetched Football entity.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear why you have a `PlayersList` entity if you aren't going to add any attributes. Either it should be a `Team` entity with a `teamName`, or the `PlayersList` should have a `purpose` or something like that.

Also, having multiple entities for different types of players is overkill. You should have a single `Player` entity with a `type` attribute that you set based on the different types of player. Then use `type` in your fetch predicate.

Now you just fetch `Player` entity and specify the appropriate `type`. If you don't specify a `type` predicate then all `Player`s will be returned (and you can use the `type` to display as football / basketball if they look different).

---

From your updated comments, you can't do everything you want in 1 set way.

If you want a single list of multiple entity types then a fetched results controller isn't a good option. You could use 2 FRCs and manage different sections on the table with each (modifying the section numbers), but generally doing 2 fetch requests and merging the results into a single array is easier.

Comment: Hmm.First of all. Thank you for answers and edited my question.Please think this project. I want to list all vehicles. User will add Cars and bikes with their names. And I want to list them with my TableViewController. User can see his cars and bikes if he wants, can look details or add details. What will you do if you want to create this project ? Will you create a Vehicles entity ? if No. How can you list these 2 different entities from your TableViewController ? Thank you very much again.

Comment: It depends on the overall requirements and the differences between the potential entities. Often multiple entities will work and wont be displayed as a single list but in a categorised list (which is logical for the user) so then you don't need to combine in the way you discuss.

Comment: Hmmm. So Can you give an example for Vehicle project ?

Comment: For example you would have a tab which shows you cars and a tab which shows your bikes, so they are logically separate on the UI. If you did show in 1 list you would show cars first and then bikes (so under the hood it still doesn't need to be one list, it can be 2 lists used in 2 different sections of a table...)